# Show that the set of the radii of the disks in $S$ is bounded

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(b,c)\subseteq\Bbb R$ be an open interval. $S$ is a set of disjoint closed disks in $\Bbb R^2$, such that $\forall s\in S \ \exists x\in (b,c)$ such that $(x,0)\in s$. Show that the set of the radii of the disks in $S$ is bounded.

If $S$ is finite than it's obvious. Otherwise, I've tried saying that if the set of the radii of the disks in $S$ weren't bounded, than the disks couldn't be disjoint. How can I formalize this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $b<x<c<0$, if $S$ has two elements $s_1,s_2$ then $(x_1,0)$ and $(x_2,0)$ must both contain $c$ so they are not disjoint.  So $S$ contains only one element.

Comment: It says $(x,0)\in s$, not $(x,0)\subseteq s$ -- thus $(x,0)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^2$, not an interval in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I see. It says $(x,0)\in s$ not $(x,0)\in S$. So then $S$ is supposed to be a set of disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, that should be stated in the question.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes, I'm sorry

Comment: Is the statement supposed to be true regardless of whether the disks are open or closed?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales they're closed disks